# OpenGL standard unit measure

Tags: image, opengl, import, size, textures

I am tring to import an image in an OpenGl project as background for a scene.

```
loadTGA("Textures\\greenhill_positive_x.tga",skyboxTexture[1]); 
sizeX = 20.0; sizeY = 20.0; sizeZ = 3.0;
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skyboxTexture[1]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);glVertex3f(sizeX, -sizeY, -sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);glVertex3f(-sizeX, -sizeY, -sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);glVertex3f(-sizeX, -sizeY, sizeZ);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);glVertex3f(sizeX, -sizeY, sizeZ);
glEnd();
```

The code works well but the texture is resized to fit `sizeX`, `sizeY`, `sizeZ` values. The size of `tga` file is 250x250 px. What values should I pass to `sizeX`, `sizeY`, `sizeZ` to match the image size?

Comment: That depends on your projection and modelview matrices. If they are identity, then the point (-1,-1,0) maps to the lower-left corner of your ***viewport*** (which has the same dimensions as your window initially) and (1,1,0) maps to the top-right corner. It's called Normalized Device Coordinate space.

Answer (score 2):

if you *load identity matrices* for all modes then it's just:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);glVertex3f(-1, 1, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);glVertex3f(-1, -1, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);glVertex3f(1, -1, 0);
glEnd();
```

you should disable depth writing and testing.